# ¿Cómo migrar de jquery a javascript 'each(function({}))'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy migrando un fragmento de código que tengo en jquery. Es el siguiente:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    var ele = document.getElementById('holamundo');
    if(esVisible(ele)== true){
      $('.counter').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
        countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
        $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
          countNum: countTo
        },
        {
          duration: 2000,
          easing:'linear',
          step: function() {
            $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
          },
          complete: function() {
            $this.text(this.countNum);
          }
        });  
      });
    }else{
    }
  });
  function esVisible(elem){
    var posTopView = $(window).scrollTop();
    var posButView = posTopView + $(window).height();
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).outerHeight();
    return ((elemBottom < posButView && elemBottom > posTopView) || (elemTop >posTopView && elemTop< posButView));
  }
```

Hasta el momento he logrado pasar lo siguiente:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    const ele = document.getElementById('holamundo');
    if(esVisible(ele)== true){
      document.getElementsByClassName('counter').foreach( function(element){
        countTo = element.getAttribute('data-count');
        
      });
      

    }else{

    }
   
  };
```

pero me arroja un error en foreach:

> uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).forEach is not a function

Hasta el momento esto me causa conflicto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto sucede porque `document.getElementsByClassName()` [retorna un `HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), no un array.

Si en verdad deseás utilizar `document.getElementsByClassName()`, se puede convertir el resultado a un array:

1. Utilizando [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from),
2. Utilizando el [operador *spread* (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Para el caso 1:

```
elementos = document.getElementsByClassName('counter')
arrayElementos = Array.from(elementos)
```

y el caso 2:

```
elementos = document.getElementsByClassName('counter')
arrayElementos = [...elementos]
```

A partir de esto, sí podrás utilizar el método [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

Como otras alternativas, se puede hacer lo que se menciona en las otras respuestas, como usar simplemente un `for` o hacer uso de [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), que retorna un `NodeList`, el cual sí es iterable.

Comment: muchas gracias de verdead me ayudo a entender y avanzar un poco actualizare mi pregunta ya que no comprendo nada del resto del código.

Comment: @Gomaru ¡Destruiste tu pregunta! Revierte la edición y crea una pregunta nueva (incluso puedes hacer referencia a la pregunta actual para "darle seguimiento"), ya que con el cambio que hiciste las respuestas no responden a tu pregunta actual. Por cierto, no olvides aceptar alguna de las respuestas (para que más adelante la pregunta no se relance una y otra vez al inicio).

Comment: claro como la revierto perdón ??

Comment: @Gomaru Si te fijás, al pie tu pregunta dice "editada hace x minutos". Pulsá ese enlace: luego verás que tu pregunta tiene 3 revisiones (la 3 es la actual). En la revisión anterior (la 2 en este caso), te vas a fijar que hay un enlace que dice "revertir". El pop-up te preguntará si realmente querés revertir la edición, entoncés allí debés pulsar el botón que también dice "revertir".

Answer (score 3):

Si no me equivoco el error lo obtienes porque estas tratando de recorrer un objeto no iterable, tiene que ser un *array o json*, esto lo veo al obtener los elementos con clase **counter**.

Cambia:
`getElementsByClassName('counter')`

Por: `querySelectorAll('.counter')`

Este genera un objeto iterable y puedes recorrerlo.

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByClassName retorna un [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) el cual no tiene la función foreach.

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
let elementos = document.getElementsByClassName('counter');
for (let element of elementos) {
    countTo = element.getAttribute('data-count');
}
```

o

```
document.querySelectorAll(".counter").forEach(
    function(element){
        countTo = element.getAttribute('data-count');
    }
)
```